# Why am I getting this error on okta-react Security component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, okta

I am trying to implement Okta into the project I am working on and following the instructions posted here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-react, I added the following in the Router of the project,

```
import React from 'react';
import HelloWorld from '@root/components/HelloWorld';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SecureRoute, Security, LoginCallback } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';

const TestPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is my test page!!!</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

const Protected = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Protected page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

const oktaDomain = // Added my okta domain here
const clientId = // Added my client id here
const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(
    {
        issuer: `https://${oktaDomain}.com/oauth2/default`,
        clientId: `${clientId}`,
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/login/callback'
    }
)


const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Security
                oktaAuth={oktaAuth}
            >
                <Route path="/" component={HelloWorld} exact={true} />
                <Route path="/test" component={TestPage} exact={true} />
                <SecureRoute path='/protected' component={Protected} />
                <Route path='/login/callback' component={LoginCallback} />
            </Security>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
};

export default AppRouter;
```

So This is how my AppRouter.tsx looks like,

If I remove this Security component layer I can see the app without any errors, but if I add Security back as the example shows I get the following error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
> at Security (Security.tsx:38)

If I click to see the line that failed I see:

[image]

What Am I missing Here?

Thank you in Advance )

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Here's what worked for me:

update the package:
react-router-dom to version 5.2.0

if you are using Redux,
try updating the version of react-redux to version 6.x.x

if issue still persisits,
use connected-react-router instead of react-router-redux.
Here are the steps to migrate from react-router-redux to connected-react-router:
https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/74